# Push in a new table view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uistoryboard

So I am aware this question has been asked many many times, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I've tried everything. 
ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>     {
NSMutableArray *tableData;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *tableData;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   {
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
SubTableView *secondView = [[SubTableView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubTableView" bundle:nil];
if ([[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Campus"]) {
    secondView.selected = 1;
    //[subTable setTitle:[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

}
if ([[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"School"]) {
    secondView.selected = 2;

}
if ([[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Admissions"]) {
    secondView.selected = 3;

    //[subTable setTitle:[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
if ([[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Boarding"]) {
    secondView.selected = 4;

}
if ([[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Academics"]) {
    secondView.selected = 4;

 }
    if ([[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Athletics"]) {
    secondView.selected = 5;

}
if ([[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Jobs"]) {
    secondView.selected = 6;


}
if ([[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Donate"]) {
    secondView.selected = 7;
}
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
    }
```

I have a NavigationController set up, although I don't know if it's properly linked in Storyboard.
The second view controller SubTableView I have set up in StoryBoard with it's own .h and .m controllers. And I have the identifier as "SubTableView" But it refuses to push that view.
The only possible thing I can think of is not having the navigationController linked properly. But I haven't been able to find anything that I can use on it.

If I put a breakpoint when

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
```

It will hit it and stop. But it will not push the new view over.

Comment: At your breakpoint, are both `self.navigationController` and `secondView` defined?  It is possible for either or both of them to be `nil` at that point.

Answer (score 0):

is `SubTableView` a subclass of `UIViewController` or `UIView`?  You need to push View Controllers onto the stack, not Views.